# How do I make parent resouce dependant ID's like on Github?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, github

In Github, the Issues system has ID's like so

```
/<user>/<repository>/issues/<issue_number>
```

the issue number is not the database ID, as then it would be something like 2323237 not 5.

In rails, I want to do the same with my site. For example

```
/people/5/hats/1
```

should give the fifth persons first hat, not the first hat in the DB table.
Therefore

```
/people/5/hats/1
```

would not be the same as

```
/people/6/hats/1
```

Any idea how to implement this in rails? Any links to tutorials maybe?

Comment: No it is not :P ;) There is question for oposite effect as current quesiont.

Comment: @przemo_li Hmm, I don't think so. But maybe I'm wrong, could you elaborate on how it's different?

Comment: Thanks, the answer to the question ye linked works well. I don't know what to do with this question now.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic should be in the show controller of hats

```
resources :people do 
  resources :hats
end
```